# PHP access child of SimpleXMLObject?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a SimpleXMLElement like this `var_dump()`:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["currencyId"]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(5) "10.44"
}
```

How do I access that `[0]` element?

`$data[0]` gives me

```
Object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["currencyId"]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried $data[1]?  Not sure if that's a solution... but it may work?

Comment: This will be easier to solve if you show the XML that produced this object.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` element you're seeing is how `SimpleXMLElement` handles nodes. Because each `SimpleXMLElement` may represent a single node or multiple, internally it keeps each node under an index.

To access the value, simply cast `$data` as a primitive type

```
$value = (double) $data;
```